# Why is my Xaml control giving me a multiple CodeBehind exception?

Tags: .net, xaml, sitecore

I have added a Xaml control to my Sitecore instance and for some reason it returning an `Only one <CodeBeside> tag is allowed on each page` exception. The problem is that there was only one CodeBeside tag in the application (see below). I even tried removing the one CodeBeside tag and I still have the same problem. How do I resolve this?

```
<control xmlns:def="Definition"
         xmlns="http://schemas.sitecore.net/Visual-Studio-Intellisense">
  <doThingy>
    <FormDialog Icon="Business/32x32/messages.png"
                Header="Thingy-doer"
                Text="Double-click each comment to edit or delete."
                OKButton="Close"
                CancelButton="false">
      <CodeBeside Type="Name.space.layout.layouts.Xaml.Dothingy.CommentsDisplayCodeBeside,CHLIHB.Web" />
      <div>Showing comments from between these dates:</div>
      <div style="outer-datepicker">
        <DatePicker ID="DateLowerBound"
                    Width="50%" />
        <DatePicker ID="DateUpperBound"
                    Width="50%" />
        <div style="clear:both" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <Scrollbox>
          <Listview ID="ThingyListItems"
                    View="Details"
                    Width="100%"
                    Background="white"
                    DblClick="nm:doubleclick"
                    Click="nm:headerclick">
            <ListviewHeader id="IndexHeader">
              <ListviewHeaderItem Name="userName"
                                  Header="User Name" />
              <ListviewHeaderItem Name="datePosted"
                                  Header="Date Posted" />
              <ListviewHeaderItem Name="contentTitle"
                                  Header="Article Title" />
              <ListviewHeaderItem Name="commentExcerpt"
                                  Header="Excerpt" />
            </ListviewHeader>
          </Listview>
        </Scrollbox>
      </div>
    </FormDialog>
  </doThingy>
</control>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause is two fold.

- You have moved the control within the project
- You probably do not have a specific enough `controlSources` node in your web.config and it is finding an old version of the Xaml control. It seems that sometimes Sitecore will ignore the second control found, and sometimes it will try to parse both (thus the exception).

Remember, there is no guarantee that Visual Studio will clean up Xaml files which have been left behind after the source has been moved. That means that generally, this is a bad policy and should be avoided:

```
<source mode="on" namespace="Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls" 
        folder="/layout" deep="true" />
```

Instead make sure you are pointing to a specific folder and (ideally) have `deep="false"`:

```
<source mode="on" namespace="Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls" 
        folder="/layout/layouts/Xaml/Dothingy" deep="false" />
```

This may mean including more `source` nodes, but it actually leads to more stability overall.